# How to disable a function on specifics custom Wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a website which has a specific plugin function to display on posts.

`<?=function_exists('za_show_button') ? za_show_button("Download") : ''?>`

I want to disable it on certain posts but mostly keep it on the others. How can I do this?

Comment: Its not about making the function vanish, but just use some other possibility to not show the button. For example categorize your posts and do something like <?=function_exists(...) && get_the_category() == "do_not_show_button" ?show_button(...):""?>

Comment: @ju_ Thank you for your reply, I have a lot of posts so how could I implement the 'get_post_type' with my current code? I'm not knowledgeable in PHP so I thank you very much :)

Comment: You can just add catgories via the wordpress interface (see this [link](https://easywpguide.com/wordpress-manual/categories/)), if you have a lot of existing posts, you would probably do best to automate this process of adding a category via a cli script - given you have some basic programming knowledge. You may also have a look at [this link about bulk editing posts](https://bobwp.com/assigning-or-changing-categories-for-bulk-posts-in-wordpress/) . You can then access this category via the [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) function.